# OpenShift git error “unable to look up current user in the passwd file: no such user”

Tags: git, github, passwords, openshift

I created a proyect in a starter version.

Later I wanted to clone a private repository.

After entering user and password I got

```
remote: Counting objects: 2357, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (197/197), done.remote: Total 2357 (delta 202), reused 278 (delta 147), pack-reused 1993
Receiving objects: 100% (2357/2357), 3.63 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (815/815), done.
fatal: unable to look up current user in the passwd file: no such user
Unexpected end of command stream
```

Comment: Need more information. What exact steps did you take to create the application? Is this with a S2I build or docker build? Make sure you review this series of posts to see if set up use of private Git repository properly. https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-1-best-practices/

Comment: I went to the browse catalog and selected a Node.js option. I did read all the steps to setup de private Git "properly" but, I did not implement any of this. Why isn't this as simple as git clone and provide credentials?

Comment: Your comment "I did not implement any of this" is confusing. Are you saying you didn't do any of the steps as described in the blog posts? Where exactly are you seeing that error, in the build logs from OpenShift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have run into a bug in certain versions (pre-2.7.0) of Git.  The workaround is to supply `user.name` and `user.email` configuration items during your `git clone` step, or upgrade your Git version.

See [this commit](https://github.com/NetSys/bess/commit/7d96bd1c070489beb68657e4c26f5ffee19c90aa) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. It is also possible to export two environmental variables GIT_COMMITTER_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL with the values you mentioned.

Comment: Same works for docker + Jenkins if you need something like `git checkout -b ...`